# (Godot) How can I stop the movement animation after my character stops moving?

Tags: godot, godot4

Here is the code;

```
func _input(event):
    if event.is_action_pressed("move_right"):
        $player_animator.play("walking_animation")
    if event.is_action_pressed("move_left"):
        $player_animator.play("walking_animation")
    if event.is_action_pressed("move_up"):
        $player_animator.play("walking_animation")
    if event.is_action_pressed("move_down"):
        $player_animator.play("walking_animation")
```

I tried using .stop to $player_animator (the animation player). Then I tried making a variable "is running" and making that variable false normally and true while I pressed the movement keys. But they all failed to do anything.

Answer (score 1):

Calling `stop()` on the `AnimationPlayer` *should* stop the animation, but the problem might be: when/where are you calling it?

You are currently using `func _input(event)`, which is event-based input handling. A single event is sent when a key is pressed, and another when the key is released. You could handle the `is_action_released` as well, and call `AnimationPlayer.stop()` there. But you would need to do this for all used keys.

The easier solution is to switch to polling-based input handling. Considering your player is a `CharacterBody`, you can implement `func _physics_process(delta)`:

```
func _physics_process(delta):
if Input.is_action_pressed("move_right"):
    $player_animator.play("walking_animation")
elif Input.is_action_pressed("move_left"):
    $player_animator.play("walking_animation")
elif Input.is_action_pressed("move_up"):
    $player_animator.play("walking_animation")
elif Input.is_action_pressed("move_down"):
    $player_animator.play("walking_animation")
else:
    $player_animator.stop()
```

The [CharacterBody2D tutorial](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/tutorials/physics/using_character_body_2d.html) lists several ways of handling input with polling. I advise using `Input.get_axis()` as it handles the case of both keys being pressed, and joysticks.